# Turn an Integer into a set of pictures

Tags: java, opengl, minecraft-forge

I am making a minecraft mod that implements a new system of "energy" for the player. There are various ways to acquire this energy and I want it to display the player's amount of energy onto the screen. My plan for this is to make a GUI (with OpenGL, as minecraft uses) that uses a file called "energybar.png":

> [image: energybar.png]

to print numbers. This is the code I have for the method that will do as described.

```
@SubscribeEvent
public void onGUIRenderEvent(RenderGameOverlayEvent event){

    if(event.isCancelable() || event.type != RenderGameOverlayEvent.ElementType.EXPERIENCE)
    {
        return;
    }

    int xPos = 10;
    int yPos = 10;
    GL11.glColor4f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

    mc.renderEngine.bindTexture(energybar);

    String energyString = Integer.toString(Energy.PlayerTotalEnergy);

    for(int i=0; i < energyString.length(); i++) {
        LogHelper.info("Energy: " + energyString);
        drawTexturedModalRect(xPos, yPos, (Energy.PlayerTotalEnergy / (int)Math.pow(10, i))*16, 0, 16, 16);
        xPos += 16;
    }

}
```

Each number in the photo is spaced out so it should be in its respective 16 pixels (ie: 0 is x positions 0-16, 1 is x positions 17-32, etc). The photo is 256x256 as defined by the standards of minecraft's GUI system. This is the layout of the method to draw a picture:

```
void drawTexturedModalRect(int xPosition, int yPosition, int uPosition, int vPosition, int width, int height)
```

The problem I have with this is that the U Positions for the numbers i need to print onto the screen are not working right.

I have also tried passing:

```
energyString.substring(i, i)
```

to a method that takes the substring and converts it back to an integer and multiplies it by 16 to get the uPosition, but when I do the:

```
String energyString = Integer.toString(Energy.PlayerTotalEnergy);
```

the `Integer.toString()` and also `String.valueOf()` methods have trouble with zeros. For example if `Energy.PlayerTotalEnergy` was just `0`, they would not return a string `"0"`, they just return `""`.

If someone could help me figure out why I can't get this to work or come up with a better idea of how I can use Minecraft and OpenGL to print this number onto my screen. The reason I'm not just printing it as a number is because I want to keep the red numbers as they look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a guess.
It seems to me that if `Energy.PlayerTotalEnergy` was, let's say, `327`, then your `uPosition` will be:

```
i=0: u= 327*16
i=1: u= 32*16
i=2: u= 3*16
```

Did you mean for them to be `7*16`, `2*16`, and `3*16`?
In that case you should `mod` them with `10`:

```
drawTexturedModalRect(xPos, yPos, ( (Energy.PlayerTotalEnergy / (int)Math.pow(10, i))%10)*16, 0, 16, 16);
```

Comment: OHHHH, I always forget about modulo XD. Thanks for the help!